# Como puedo hacer un LightBox - Modal con VueJs desde un array de Imagenes con Vfor

Tags: javascript, html, array, vue.js, modal

quisiera ayuda en hacer LightBox - Modal con VueJs desde un array de Imagenes con Vfor, como pueden ver itero el arreglo desde el Vfor y ya muestro todas las imagenes, pero quiero saber como puedo hacer un LightBox desde ahí.
Gracias de Antemano, soy nuevo con Vue.

```
<template>
    <section class="products-container">
        <article class="products-content" v-for="item in divs" :key="item.id">
            <div class="product-img">
                <img :src="item.image" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="product-title">
                <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
            </div>
        </article>

    </section>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    setup() {
        let divs = [
            { title: 'Productos Hidrobiologicos CEGERCRUZ PERU', image: require('../assets/img/produccion_productos_hidrobiologicos-10.webp')},
            { title: 'Productos Hidrobiologicos CEGERCRUZ PERU', image: require('../assets/img/produccion_productos_hidrobiologicos-11.webp')},
            { title: 'Productos Hidrobiologicos CEGERCRUZ PERU', image: require('../assets/img/produccion_productos_hidrobiologicos-12.webp')},
            { title: 'Productos Hidrobiologicos CEGERCRUZ PERU', image: require('../assets/img/produccion_productos_hidrobiologicos-13.webp')},

            { title: 'Productos Hidrobiologicos CEGERCRUZ PERU', image: require('../assets/img/produccion_productos_hidrobiologicos-16.webp')},
            { title: 'Productos Hidrobiologicos CEGERCRUZ PERU', image: require('../assets/img/produccion_productos_hidrobiologicos-17.webp')},
            { title: 'Productos Hidrobiologicos CEGERCRUZ PERU', image: require('../assets/img/produccion_productos_hidrobiologicos-15.webp')},
            { title: 'Productos Hidrobiologicos CEGERCRUZ PERU', image: require('../assets/img/produccion_productos_hidrobiologicos-19.webp')},
            { title: 'Productos Hidrobiologicos CEGERCRUZ PERU', image: require('../assets/img/produccion_productos_hidrobiologicos-7-300x225.webp')},
            { title: 'Productos Hidrobiologicos CEGERCRUZ PERU', image: require('../assets/img/produccion_productos_hidrobiologicos-6-300x192.webp')},
            { title: 'Productos Hidrobiologicos CEGERCRUZ PERU', image: require('../assets/img/produccion_productos_hidrobiologicos-5-300x198.webp')},
            { title: 'Productos Hidrobiologicos CEGERCRUZ PERU', image: require('../assets/img/produccion_productos_hidrobiologicos-29.webp')},
        
        ]
        return {
            divs
        }
    },
}

</script>
```